# Are there actions or filters I can use for Ajax calls?

Tags: filters, ajax, actions

I'm interested in writing a caching function for Ajax calls.

If a third party plugin does their thing, calls `wp_ajax_whatever`, how do I pick that off?

If a person does slideshow updates with a plugin that uses Ajax, e.g. `wp_ajax_plugin_update_slider`, I want to empty my template cache when this happens. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you  [check the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) for `admin-ajax.php` you will notice that the `admin_init` hook fires and that the system checks `$_REQUEST['action']` for hooks. Given that, you could hook to `admin_init`, check the "request" super global, construct `wp_ajax_*` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` values, then use [`has_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action) to see if anything is hooked in.